# Zend framework $db->update result

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db

`Zend_Db_Adapter::update()` returns the number of rows affected by the update operation.
What is best way to determine if the query was successful?

```php
$data = array(
    'updated_on'      => '2007-03-23',
    'bug_status'      => 'FIXED'
); 

$n = $db->update('bugs', $data, 'bug_id = 2');
```

Comment: If it's not successfull - an exception will be thrown

Comment: @zerkms I think that unless there is an adapter issue or an incorrect query that throws a Zend_Db_Statement exception update will return 0 rows if no rows are affected. However you'll likely get a Mysql/pdo error about not enough parameters bound or some such.

Comment: @RockyFord: if there is an exception - nothing will be returned from that call ever

Comment: I'm saying it won't always throw an exception. The only exception update throws is for an adapter conflict, every thing else would be peripheral. so assuming your syntax is correct and maybe the id is incorrect, you might get a sql error but you won't get a php exception.

Comment: @RockyFord: if there will be an sql error - it will be converted to an exception, won't it? "might get a sql error but you won't get a php exception" -- I'm sure there will be a php exception for that ;-)

Comment: @Reza See this answer also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10421877/zend-db-update-better-error-reporting/10422499#10422499

Comment: @zerkms Honestly I'm not sure if it'll be an exception or a fatal error.

Comment: @RockyFord: there is absolutely no reason for fatal error - the error has nothing to do with php and parser, it is just a 3rd party storage error. Which will be converted to an exception by ZF

Comment: @zerkms yup you're correct...but I learned something new. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

```
$data = array(
    'updated_on' => '2007-03-23',
    'bug_status' => 'FIXED',
);
$n = 0;
try {
    $n = $db->update('bugs', $data, 'bug_id = 2');
} catch (Zend_Exception $e) {
    die('Something went wrong: ' . $e->getMessage());
}
if (empty($n)) {
    die('Zero rows affected');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are just looking for a boolean return value, this solution is the best for handling success in the model:

class Default_Model_Test extends Zend_Db_Table {

```
public function updateTest($testId, $testData){

    try {

        $this->_db->update('test', $testData, array(
            'id = ?'        => $testId
        ));

        return true;

    }
    catch (Exception $exception){

        return false;

    }

}
```

}

But, a better solution would be to handling success from the controller level, because it is making the request:

```
class Default_Model_Test extends Zend_Db_Table {

    public function updateTest($testId, $testData){

        $this->_db->update('test', $testData, array(
            'id = ?'        => $testId
        ));

    }

}

class Default_TestController extends Zend_Controller_Action {

    public function updateAction(){

        try {

            $testId = $this->_request->getParam('testId');
            if (empty($testId)) throw new Zend_Argument_Exception('testId is empty');

            $testData = $this->_request->getPost();
            if (empty($testId)) throw new Zend_Argument_Exception('testData is empty');

            $testModel->updateTest($testId, $testData);

        }
        catch (Exception $exception){

            switch (get_class($exception)){

                case 'Zend_Argument_Exception': $message = 'Argument error.'; break;
                case 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception': $message = 'Database error.'; break;
                case default: $message = 'Unknown error.'; break;

            }

        }

    }

}
```

This is an excellent solution when working with multiple resource types, using a switch on the exception type, and doing what is appropriate based on your program's needs.  Nothing can escape this vacuum.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
$data = array(
    'updated_on'      => '2007-03-23',

    'bug_status'      => 'FIXED'
);
$result = $db->update('bugs', $data, 'bug_id = 2');
if ($result < $numRows) {//pass in numRows as method arg or hardcode integer.
    //handle error
} else {
    return TRUE;
}
```

Try something like this with the idea being you want to verify that the number of records you wanted updated got updated.

Comment: number of actually updated rows depends on the original values. So even if `$result` equals to 0 - then it doesn't mean something wrong happened