# How do I test if insert query was successfully executed in zend 2?

Tags: pdo, zend-framework2, zend-db

This is my code:

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$insert =   $this->adapter->query("INSERT INTO users (username,`name`,email,`password`, birthday,country,city,address,website,img_url,`date`,`update`,ip,email_confirm,`status`) values ('".$new_user_data['username']."','".$new_user_data['name']."','".$new_user_data['mail']."','".md5($new_user_data['password'])."','".$new_user_data['birthday']."','".$new_user_data['country']."','".$new_user_data['city']."','".$new_user_data['address']."','".$new_user_data['website']."','".$new_user_data['user_picture']."',NOW(),
                NOW(),'".$ip."','0','normal')");
$check = $insert->execute();
```

I want to check if the insert query was executed with success. How can i do that ?

Comment: this can be effected for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14890247/zend-framework-2-sql-update-and-insert-affected-rows-zf2

Answer (score 4):

After a little search I found the following (not tested, only theoretical):

Your code `$adapter->query('STRING')->execute()` should  return a `Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\ResultInterface` on which you could check against `$result->getAffectedRows()`.

Also:

In ZF2 it is no good practice to directly use global vars like `$_SESSION`, use `$this->getRequest()->getServer('REMOTE_ADDR');` in your controller instead.

Hope that helps

Comment: ok, but what happens when i make update a row in db, with the same data? I tested it , and it returns me 0. Actually I do not want to know if there is any affected data in the row. I just want to know if the query is executed with success.