# Add or Update if exist on table zend framework 1.11

Tags: php, zend-framework, model-view-controller, frameworks

I want update the data if exist in table Mysql else I Add the data so I do this script but just Add not do Update if already exist if id

```
public function addUpdateCust(array $data)
{

    if(!empty($data))
    {
        if($this->update($data, array('id = ?' => $data['id'])) > 0 )
        {
            return true;
        }
        $row = $this->createRow();
        //$row->id           = $data['id'];
        $row->code           = $data['code'];
        $row->fabname        = $data['fabname'];
        $row->namecustomer   = $data['namecustomer'];
        $row->adresse        = $data['adresse'];           
        $row->city           = $data['city'];           
        $row->zipcode        = $data['zipcode'];           
        $row->country        = $data['country'];           
        $row->phone          = $data['phone'];       
        $row->representative = $data['representative'];
        $row->idUser         = NULL;

        //var_dump($row);
        try {
            return $row->save();           
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return $e;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are not saying what is not working. We expect you to put as much effort in asking your question as you expect from us answering it.

Comment: This should be working. Check if `$data` has correct data.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should be using try/catch for that. update does not return true or false like you seem to think.

```
public function addUpdateCust(array $data)
{

    if(!empty($data))
    {
        try{
            $this->update($data, array('id = ?' => $data['id']);
        } catch (Zend_Exception $e) {
            $row = $this->createRow();
            //$row->id           = $data['id'];
            $row->code           = $data['code'];
            $row->fabname        = $data['fabname'];
            $row->namecustomer   = $data['namecustomer'];
            $row->adresse        = $data['adresse'];           
            $row->city           = $data['city'];           
            $row->zipcode        = $data['zipcode'];           
            $row->country        = $data['country'];           
            $row->phone          = $data['phone'];       
            $row->representative = $data['representative'];
            $row->idUser         = NULL;

            //var_dump($row);
            try {
                return $row->save();           
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                return $e;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11495787/323839)

Comment: so i want update if exist this id on table else i want to insert add the data tanhks to help me

Comment: Well thats it. If update fails (record does not exist) then you catch the exception and create from there. Like in my example. If you do not know what exceptions are then you might be in over your head. We can help. Not do it for you.

Comment: i do that but not insert the data not update such as already my code can do Add but now when i do this script not do anything thanks for help

Comment: You should hire a programmer. Nothing more I can do. I am not even sure you understand the example I posted. Good luck!

Comment: i am programmer and i know good the Exception ,but when i do this script it's not work for me thanks in advance

Comment: can any one tell me how can i resolve that ,Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
public function addUpdateCust(array $data)
{

    if(!empty($data))
    {
            $row = $this->createRow();
            //$row->id           = $data['id'];
            $row->code           = $data['code'];
            $row->fabname        = $data['fabname'];
            $row->namecustomer   = $data['namecustomer'];
            $row->adresse        = $data['adresse'];           
            $row->city           = $data['city'];           
            $row->zipcode        = $data['zipcode'];           
            $row->country        = $data['country'];           
            $row->phone          = $data['phone'];       
            $row->representative = $data['representative'];
            $row->idUser         = NULL;

            //var_dump($row);
            try {
                return $row->save();
            } catch (Zend_Exception $e) {
               $this->update($data, array('id = ?' => $data['id']);
            }
        return true;
    }
}
```